# Oracle SQL - Remove Duplicate and Keep Row That Has the Maximum Value

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, max

```
SELECT
t.trade_id,    
co.name,     
t.shares,   
se.name


FROM trade t
JOIN company co
ON co.stock_id = t.stock_id
JOIN stock_exchange se
ON se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
WHERE  se.stock_ex_id IS NOT NULL AND t.shares =( SELECT MAX(t.shares) FROM trade  )
GROUP BY t.trade_id, co.name, t.shares, se.name
ORDER BY co.name
;
```

This query displays duplicate company names along with different share values. My question is how do you remove the duplicate company names and only display the company names with the maximum share value based on its duplicates?

I tried using this line `t.shares =( SELECT MAX(t.shares) FROM trade  )` to get the max share values, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's a picture of the table it's displaying:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to display distinct company name with max share value of the company?

Comment: Yes. I want the distinct company names with the max shares value of the company.

Comment: Below i have posted one query please check and let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query it will display the company names with the maximum share value

```
select trade_id,name,shares,name_1 from 
    (
    SELECT
    t.trade_id,    
    co.name as name,
    t.shares,   
    se.name as name_1,
    row_number() over (partition by co.name order by t.shares desc) as R_no
    FROM trade t
    JOIN company co
    ON co.stock_id = t.stock_id
    JOIN stock_exchange se
    ON se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
    WHERE  se.stock_ex_id IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY t.trade_id, co.name, t.shares, se.name
    ORDER BY co.name
    )
    where R_no=1
```

Comment: It doesn't work. You listed `name` twice on the first line. Try to use my query.  My teacher actually added something like `t.shares =( SELECT MAX(t.shares) FROM trade  )` to my query to get the results(and he removed it afterwards), I forgot the code that he added when I tried to implement it myself. lol

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I created the test data correctly and understood the requirement:

```
WITH trade AS (
    SELECT 31 TRADE_ID, 1 STOCK_ID, 1 STOCK_EX_ID, 4000 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 52 TRADE_ID, 1 STOCK_ID, 1 STOCK_EX_ID, 1000 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 TRADE_ID, 2 STOCK_ID, 2 STOCK_EX_ID, 2300 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 18 TRADE_ID, 2 STOCK_ID, 2 STOCK_EX_ID, 72000 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 23 TRADE_ID, 2 STOCK_ID, 2 STOCK_EX_ID, 24000 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 25 TRADE_ID, 2 STOCK_ID, 2 STOCK_EX_ID, 400 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 39 TRADE_ID, 2 STOCK_ID, 2 STOCK_EX_ID, 2300 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 44 TRADE_ID, 2 STOCK_ID, 2 STOCK_EX_ID, 25000 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 46 TRADE_ID, 2 STOCK_ID, 2 STOCK_EX_ID, 400 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 16 TRADE_ID, 3 STOCK_ID, 1 STOCK_EX_ID, 1500 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 17 TRADE_ID, 3 STOCK_ID, 1 STOCK_EX_ID, 24000 SHARES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 21 TRADE_ID, 3 STOCK_ID, 1 STOCK_EX_ID, 1500 SHARES FROM DUAL
),
company AS (
    SELECT 1 STOCK_ID, 'BNP Paribas' NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 STOCK_ID, 'British Airways' NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 STOCK_ID, 'EDF' NAME FROM DUAL
),
stock_exchange AS (
    SELECT 1 STOCK_EX_ID, 'Euronext Paris' NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 STOCK_EX_ID, 'London Stock Exchange' NAME FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    MAX(trade_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY shares) trade_id,
    co.name,     
    MAX(shares) maxshares,
    MAX(se.name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY shares) stock_exchange_name
FROM
    trade t
    JOIN company co ON co.stock_id = t.stock_id
    JOIN stock_exchange se ON se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
WHERE
    se.stock_ex_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    co.name
ORDER BY
    co.name
```